# hibernate delete query not working when it is fired from my app

Tags: mysql, hibernate

```
String query = DElETE from Photo where pId = :id and photoName = :name;
getSession().createQuery(query).setParameter("id", id)
.setParameter("name", name).executeUpdate();
```

The above does not work when it executes from my app. the query I got from this is,

```
delete from photo where id = 77 and photo_name = '77-Hollywood-Star.jpg';
```

i even used

> createSQLQuery(delete from photo where id = 77 and photo_name = '77-Hollywood-Star.jpg';)

but no use!

The above works when I run this in mysql.

Comment: did you flushed session and committed transaction?

Comment: thanks LMG, it worked after committing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well then by the comment I understand you only needed to commit the transaction.

Remember that hibernate is pretty a complex framework, and if you don't use entity manager you have to manage transaction by your self!

Cheers

LG

Answer (score 0):

I assume that above mentioned code was your actual code which you used for your testing purpose or whatsoever.I suspect their is some mismatch in your parameter names but not sure. can please post here your exception details?

Cheers!